# How to disable incoming & outgoing calls in android phone

Tags: android

I want to disable the feature of incoming and outgoing calls in the Android phone.My android phone should only allow GPRS & other applications to be run.

**My Android model is Samsung Ace**

Please suggest me solution regarding this. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4):

This code will block your all **call (INCOMING AND OUTGOING)**

```
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

import android.content.Context;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

import com.CallLogApp.helper.BlockNumberHelper;
import com.CallLogApp.util.UDF;
import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;

public class CustomPhoneStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {

    //private static final String TAG = "PhoneStateChanged";
    Context context;
    public CustomPhoneStateListener(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String outGoingNumber) {
        super.onCallStateChanged(state, outGoingNumber);

        switch (state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                endCallIfBlocked(outGoingNumber);
                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

     }

     private void endCallIfBlocked(String outGoingNumber) {
        try {
            // Java reflection to gain access to TelephonyManager's
            // ITelephony getter
            TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            Class<?> c = Class.forName(tm.getClass().getName());
            Method m = c.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            m.setAccessible(true);
            com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);  

            if (new BlockNumberHelper(context).isBlocked(outGoingNumber))
            {
                telephonyService = (ITelephony) m.invoke(tm);
                telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                telephonyService.endCall();
            }


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Here CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK state will call each time when your call going to connect and when you received incoming call**

There is no any method that **you can know weather it is incoming call or outgoing call**

But you can end call which is going to connect in both scenario

Comment: What is com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony and BlockNumberHelper here ?

Answer (score 2):

**Anything you delevop using google's android API..**

Would be located in the Applications layer of [Android's architcture](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/index.html). But managing calls is something implemented in the Applications Framework layer.  So:

- If you want to block calls from an application you can't avoid the phone call state to happen, so once the telephony manager has handled the call, end it with telephonyService.endCall().
- If you really need calls not to reach your application layer.. I think a custom android compilation would be needed
- **But have you considered** that some mobile telephony providers offer "data cards" for which they block voice channels?  These are the kind of cards that come in 3G mobile internet modems